# Structural definition of "product" in set theory

Tags: set-theory, ct.category-theory

At first sight there is no abstract (= structural) definition of "product" in set theory. E.g. the Cartesian product of sets $A$ and $B$ is defined as the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$, $x \in A$, $y \in B$, and thus depends on the definition of "ordered pair" which is notoriously arbitrary.

I wonder if the following can count as an abstract (= structural) definition of "product" in the context of set theory.

Consider a set $S$ with two equivalence relations $\sim_1$ and $\sim_2$.

> **Definition**: $(S,\sim_1,\sim_2)$ is a product iff 
>   $$(\forall x \in S)(\forall y \in S)(\exists ! z\in S) x \sim_1 z \wedge y \sim_2 z$$
>   $$(\forall z\in S)(\exists ! x\in S)(\exists ! y\in S) x \sim_1 z \wedge y \sim_2 z$$

If $(S,\sim_1,\sim_2)$ is a product

- $S$ can be understood as $S/_{\sim_1} \times S/_{\sim_2}$
- the relations $\sim_i$ can be read as *has the same $i$-th component*
- the canonical projection map $\pi_i (x) = [x]_{\sim_i}$ can be understood as the *$i$-th component*

> **Question:** Isn't this definition somehow on par - concerning
>   structuralness - with the definition
>   of category theory? If so, why is it
>   so rarely found, or rather: *where* can
>   I find it (in which textbook, e.g.)?

Considering the product of a set with itself, i.e. $S = X \times X$, one relation $\sim$ does suffice, which does not have to be an equivalence relation, not even symmetric, but from which two equivalence relations can be defined:

$$ x \sim_1 y :\equiv (\exists z) x \sim z \wedge y \sim z $$
$$ x \sim_2 y :\equiv (\exists z) z \sim x \wedge z \sim y $$

If $(S,\sim_1,\sim_2)$ is a product the relation $x \sim y$ can be read as *the first component of $x$ equals the second component of $y$*.

> **Question**: Are there conditions on a relation $\sim$ such that $\sim_1$,
>   $\sim_2$ as defined above make
>   $(S,\sim_1,\sim_2)$ automatically a
>   product?

Comment: In your definition of a product, did you mean $\forall x \in S \forall y \in S \exists! z \in S \ldots$ instead of the unbounded quantification $\forall x \forall y \exists! z \ldots$?

Comment: The definition of a product should involve three sets, not just one. If I tell you that $P$ is a product of two sets, you cannot always recover from $P$ the two sets (think of the case when one of the sets is empty).

Your definition is unlikely going to work when one of the components is an empty set. How would we get $\emptyset \times \mathbb{N}$, for example? If you take $S = \emptyset$, as you presumably should, then you cannot recover $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Andrej: Yes, of course I did mean $(\forall x \in S)$ etc. I hoped this would be clear from the context.

Comment: Is the empty set case the only problematic one (in this context)?

Comment: The second condition is not satisfied by usual products in general.

Comment: I understand that I might be a bit sheltered, but: at what point did the definition of ordered pair become 'notoriously arbitrary'?

Comment: I just wanted to say that there are *many* definitions of "ordered pair" and none of them is distinguished.

Comment: I would regard the `definition' of ordered pair in ZFC (or similarly) merely as a proof of existence of ordered pairs/products. Just as there are many constructions of the natural numbers, integers, rationals, real and complex numbers. Really, what matters is the relations between the objects.

Comment: And I'd think of the product $X\times Y$ in terms of the projections $X\times Y\to X$, $X\times Y\to Y$. Of course, functions/homomorphisms are not part of the definition of ZFC, so have to be constructed --- usually after the construction of pairs and products.

Comment: The product of sets, *together* with its projection maps to the factors, could be characterized by a suitable universal mapping property. Then that construction is unique up to suitable isomorphism as all objects satisfying universal properties are. This can let you relax a little about the fact that there may be more than one way to make the construction of a product of sets (and its projections to the factors). 

Comment: The category theory also makes it clear why there can be no acceptable definition. Because a product is an object with structure (in the form of two functions), and there is no intrinsic definition for structure.

Comment: @George: "what matters is the relations between the objects" - that's what I tried to capture with my definition: ordered pairs are atomic objects, kept together by some relations.

Comment: @Hans Stricker: Right, so I partly agree with you there. Except, rather than adding a pair of relations, I think adding a 'Pair' keyword is neater. This is a 2-ary function symbol satisfying the axiom $$\forall x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\;\left(({\rm Pair}(x_1,x_2)={\rm Pair}(y_1,y_2))\rightarrow(x_1=y_1 \wedge x_2=y_2)\right).$$ Or, add another pair $\pi_1,\pi_2$ of 1-ary functions satisfying $$\forall x,y\;\left(\pi_1{\rm Pair}(x,y)=x\wedge\pi_2{\rm Pair}(x,y)=y\right).$$ In any case, I don't think that ZFC style set theory on its own is really designed to be a handy framework for actually doing maths.

Comment: To amplify a-fortiori's comment: The second clause in your definition says, when the notation is understood as explained right after the definition, that for each $z$ there is just one $x$ with just one $y$ such that $z$ agrees with $x$ in the first component and with $y$ in the second.  In fact, there are as many such $x$'s (resp. $y$'s) as the cardinality of the quotient `$S/\sim_1$` (resp. `$S/\sim_2$`).  The first component of $x$ must agree with that of $z$ but the second is arbitrary; similarly for $y$. 

Comment: @Hans Stricker: I see that you are trying to define the concept of an ordered pair *without* defining the components of the pair itself, which my previous comment missed. Not sure why though.

Comment: @Hans Stricker: I see that you are trying to define the concept of a product *without* refering to its individual components, which my previous comment missed. Not sure why though. 

Comment: "I don't think that ZFC style set theory on its own is really designed to be a handy framework for actually doing maths." +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

How do you define an equivalence relation in ZF without refering to products or ordered pairs? In case you want to define products via the usual universal property: There you have to use maps, which probably also cannot defined without ordered pairs in ZF.

Anyway, if you are interested in a category theoretic foundation of set theory and therefore of all mathematics, you might be interested in Lawvere's [Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS).

Comment: @Martin: Is this true: do I really need *ordered* pairs to define an equivalence relation, don't unordered pairs suffice?

Comment: Please write down your definition of an equivalence relation which does not use ordered pairs.

Comment: @Martin - Because of symmetry, you should actually be able to: Define an equivalence relation on $S$ as a subset $R$ of the collection of subsets of $S$ whose cardinality is at most 2 satisfying a) For all $x \in S$, $\lbrace x \rbrace \in R$. b) For all $x, y, z \in S$, if $\lbrace x, y \rbrace \in R$ and $\lbrace y, z \rbrace \in R$, then $\lbrace x, z \rbrace \in R$. This should do the trick.

Comment: That's what I had in mind. Is there a flaw?

Comment: Interesting, this seems to work.

Comment: Another natural way is to represent an equivalence relation by the partition it induces (i.e., an equivalence relation on $S$ is a set of nonempty disjoint sets whose union is $S$).

Answer (score 0):

From your first part of  definition from a couple  $x,\ y$ of elements of $S$,  there is (uniquely) associated  an element $z$ of $S$ still, then  essentially we have that $ S \times S \subset S $ (exist a subset of $S$ in bijection by the usual $S\times S$) and from second part this inclusion is a equality. Then your definitions dont work for finite sets for example.